# What is the output of an InputBox command that is left empty

Tags: autohotkey

What is the output of an InputBox command that is left empty

[image]

Is there a good way to check if the feild was left empty

like `if OutputVar = "" { goto, restart }`

i've tried the solution above and it didn't work for me any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
InputBox, text, Enter Text

if(text)
    MsgBox Something was inputed
else{
    MsgBox Nothing was inputed
    goto restart
}
```

The output of an empty InputBox is not a value, so you can just check whether or not the variable you store the output as has a value or not through an `if(variable)` statement.

### Edit responding to comment:

AHK is special in that you do not need a boolean value (i.e. True or False) within an if statement in order for it to work (in contrast to traditional programming languages). In ahk, if the value inside the parenthesis of an if statement is a non-boolean data type (i.e. a number), the program will treat it as `true` if the value is non-zero. This can be seen with the following code:

```
text:=0 ; Alternatively: text:=""

if(text)
    MsgBox True was triggered!
else
    MsgBox False was triggered!
```

### Another Edit after I noticed something:

The idea behind the code you had above also works, provided that you move the curly braces/ content to the next line.

So either

```
if (text = "")
{
    MsgBox hello 
}
```

or

```
if (text = "")
    MsgBox hello
```

is also fine.

Comment: i dont really get how it works don't you need an operator for the if(text) part but it still works fine

Comment: I added 2 edits to clarify this @fatestcatever420. If you need any more clarification, lmk.